# Parse one-to-many (array/children) relationship

Tags: android, parse-platform

I have a parent let's call it `myUser` which is stored in `myUser` and the children, `Post`.

Each myUser likes Posts. I store this relationship in an array in each myUser.

**I want to get the Posts that a user likes:**

```
// for a given ParseObject myUser I do:
ParseRelation relation = myUser.getRelation("likedPosts");

ParseQuery<PostParseObject> query = relation.getQuery();

query.findInBackground(new FindCallback< PostParseObject >() {
    @Override
    public void done(List<PostParseObject> posts, ParseException e) {

        if(e==null){
            System.out.println("cool");
            for(PostParseObject post: posts){
               //do something
            }
        }
    }
});
```

Unfortunately the above returns 0 posts. However in my data browser, under myUser's `likedPosts` column for the above tested user there are 4 linked Post-s:

```
[{"__type":"Pointer","className":"Post","objectId":"Y3FRUwcSph"},
{"__type":"Pointer","className":"Post","objectId":"XILJbguidS"},
{"__type":"Pointer","className":"Post","objectId":"r2UqBl8zRD"},
{"__type":"Pointer","className":"Post","objectId":"VMIIeLJhwf"}]
```

Which means that 4 Post-s should have been returned in the `public void done(List<PostParseObject> posts, ParseException e) {}`. Why that? Any help to query this one-to-many relationship?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have to "solve a puzzle" with reading parts of the docs. The full snippet is the following. Hope someone finds it helpful.

```
ParseQuery<MyUser> query = ParseQuery.getQuery("myUser");
query.include("likedPosts");

query.getInBackground(currentUserID, new GetCallback< MyUser >() {
    @Override
    public void done(MyUser mUser, ParseException e) {
        ArrayList< ParseObject > posts = (ArrayList< ParseObject >) myUser.get("likedPosts");
        for (ParseObject post : posts) {
            //do
    }
});
```